# Power BI Streaming Dataset from Data Lake Gen2

Tags: powerbi, streaming, azure-stream-analytics

We get sensor data being pushed into Data Lake as `.json` files.  Frequency is every minutes sends a `.json` file.  I wanted to do set Power BI Stream Dataset to above container Data Lake to some sought near realtime Dashboard.

What is the quickest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up Creating Stream Analytics Job, Data Lake Container where IOT devices are configured to push data in .`json` files as Input and Power BI Dataset and Output. And created report from the Power BI Dataset.